# SqlMethods.DateDiffMonth in the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Does anyone know what is the replacement for SqlMethods.DateDiffMonth in the Entity Framework.

This is the error I am getting when I tried to use it.

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 DateDiffMonth(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that, currently, you need to express this using an eSQL statement that effectively calls down to the SQLServer DATEDIFF method

For example:

```
db.entity.Where("SqlServer.DATEDIFF('MONTH', [start date], [end date]) = 1");
```

(See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/f32f3311-350d-4c2d-a4fd-c801918d36b1/) for further info)

However, when the .NET Framework Version 4.0 is released (or you can use it now if you like playing with beta software! :) you should be able to use the [DateDiff method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466229%28VS.100%29.aspx) of the new [SqlFunctions class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28VS.100%29.aspx), which is part of the new [System.Data.Objects.SqlClient Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient%28VS.100%29.aspx) in .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using LINQ to Entities the best way would be to use the following:

```
var query = query.Where(e => DateTime.Today >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(e.StartDateTime)
&& DateTime.Today <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(e.EndDateTime));
```